# Query efficient way of banding DATEDIFF(DAY) in SQL (with a pre-calculation)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I currently have two date fields, effective_date and invoice_date. I am finding the most recent date of the two, and then working out the number of days between this date and today (or whenever the report is run). Using this I'm then creating a label in an 'Ageing' column to group the results into age bands. My current code is this:

```
SELECT TOP 500 

'Ageing' = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,
                CASE WHEN tbis.invoice_date_key > tbis.effective_date_key
                     THEN tbis.invoice_date_key
                     ELSE tbis.effective_date_key
                END, GETDATE()) < 0 THEN 'Prebill'

                WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,
                CASE WHEN tbis.invoice_date_key > tbis.effective_date_key
                     THEN tbis.invoice_date_key
                     ELSE tbis.effective_date_key
                END, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 29 THEN '<30 Days'

                WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,
                CASE WHEN tbis.invoice_date_key > tbis.effective_date_key
                     THEN tbis.invoice_date_key
                     ELSE tbis.effective_date_key
                END, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 59 THEN '30+ Days'

                WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,
                CASE WHEN tbis.invoice_date_key > tbis.effective_date_key
                     THEN tbis.invoice_date_key
                     ELSE tbis.effective_date_key
                END, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 60 AND 89 THEN '60+ Days'

                WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,
                CASE WHEN tbis.invoice_date_key > tbis.effective_date_key
                     THEN tbis.invoice_date_key
                     ELSE tbis.effective_date_key
                END, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 90 AND 119 THEN '90+ Days'

                WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,
                CASE WHEN tbis.invoice_date_key > tbis.effective_date_key
                     THEN tbis.invoice_date_key
                     ELSE tbis.effective_date_key
                END, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 120 AND 179 THEN '120+ Days'

                WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,
                CASE WHEN tbis.invoice_date_key > tbis.effective_date_key
                     THEN tbis.invoice_date_key
                     ELSE tbis.effective_date_key
                END, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 180 AND 364 THEN '180+ Days'

                WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,
                CASE WHEN tbis.invoice_date_key > tbis.effective_date_key
                     THEN tbis.invoice_date_key
                     ELSE tbis.effective_date_key
                END, GETDATE()) >= 365 THEN '365+ Days'
                ELSE NULL
                END

                FROM [transaction] tbis
```

This approach works fine, but I am currently only looking at 150,000 records. Soon this will be run against potentially several million records.

As a result I'm having a look to see if I could improve how this is written. I've looked at the below using another SELECT and the MAX() approach:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, (SELECT   MAX(v)
                       FROM     ( VALUES ( t.effective_date_key), ( t.invoice_date_key) ) AS value (v)
                      ), GETDATE())
```

This works well in isolation - to obtain the days old for each record. But when nested into the above case statement it produces the below error:

**Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.**

Any thoughts on how I could achieve my aims in a more efficient way would be great. Alternatively perhaps my existing case statement is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I imagine it will be slightly faster and more reader friendly:

```
SELECT TOP 500 
'Ageing' = 
  CASE WHEN x.datedif < 0 THEN 'Prebill'
       WHEN x.datedif < 30 THEN '<30 Days'
       WHEN x.datedif < 60 THEN '30+ Days'
       WHEN x.datedif < 90 THEN '60+ Days'
       WHEN x.datedif < 120 THEN '90+ Days'
       WHEN x.datedif < 180 THEN '120+ Days'
       WHEN x.datedif >= 180 THEN '180+ Days'
       ELSE NULL
  END
FROM [transaction] tbis
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT 
      DATEDIFF(DD,
        CASE WHEN tbis.invoice_date_key > tbis.effective_date_key
        THEN tbis.invoice_date_key
        ELSE tbis.effective_date_key
      END, GETDATE()) datedif
) x
```

Comment: Fantastic. Really clean - great! Any thoughts on the max() approach vs using a case statement to identify the initial DATEDIFF?

Comment: @chris1982 in order to use max, you need to work the 2 columns into a table and use another cross apply. The case solution is much cleaner when there are only 2 columns to compare